# TikZ: Putting arrows on a font sign

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

[image]

What is the best way, to put  arrows like this on a font symbol? 
 If I change the fontsize, the example flies around my ears.

*I want consistent arrows (annotations) if I change the fontsize, e.g. `\tiny` instead of   `\Huge`.*

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach\Fontsize in {\Huge, \small}{%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\sffamily\Fontsize,
>=stealth,
No/.style={font=\sffamily\tiny, near start,  inner sep=1pt},
]
\node[draw=lightgray, minimum size=2em](symbol){A};
%% Orientation: 
%\fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
%\draw[red] (120:1.0em) -- (0,0);

\draw[->, blue] (220:1.05em) -- +(0.3em,1em) node[No, left]{1};
%% .... How to put a node on a "to-path"?
\draw[->, blue, bend left] (120:1.0em)  to[bend left] (50:1.0em);
\path[blue] (120:1.0em) -- (0,0) node[No, above left]{2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%%
```

Comment: Hello, isn't this question the same as one you posted last week ? I can't find this question anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proposal where the arrows/numbers remain at the same position regardless of the font size. With minor modifiations, it coul also adapt to the actual font size to keep de same space around the letter symbol.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\tikzset{
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}

\foreach\Fontsize in {\Huge, \small}{%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\sffamily\Fontsize,
>=stealth,
No/.style={font=\sffamily\tiny,inner sep=1pt},
]
\draw[gray,use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (8ex,8ex);
\begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
\node[] at (0.5,0.5) (symbol) {A};
\draw[->, blue] (0.1,0.1) --++ (70:0.5) node[near start,No, left]{1};
\path[draw,->,blue]
node[No,anchor=south] at (0.1,0.8) {2} 
(0.1,0.8) to[bend left] (0.9,0.8) 
;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

**ADDENDUM** : To serve for further discussion with the OP

This code produces one page per font size, where a scaling is performed to keep height constant whatever the actual font size. This is to show that characters are not scaled between font sizes, but are different.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}

\foreach\Fontsize in {\tiny,\scriptsize,\footnotesize,\small,\normalsize,\large,\Large,\LARGE,\huge,\Huge}{%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sffamily\Fontsize,
    >=stealth,
    No/.style={font=\sffamily\tiny,inner sep=1pt},
    ]
\node[draw=gray] {\resizebox{!}{\heightof{\normalsize A}}{\Fontsize A}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** After some tweaks between `scale=` at the `tikzpicture` and at the `node` level

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\tikzset{
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}

\foreach\Fontsize in 
%{\normalsize}{%
{\tiny,\scriptsize,\footnotesize,\small,\normalsize,\large,\Large,\LARGE,\huge,\Huge}{%%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\scalefactor}{height("\Fontsize A")/height("\Huge A")}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\sffamily\Fontsize,
>={Stealth[length=1ex*\scalefactor]},
No/.style={font=\sffamily\tiny,transform shape},
scale={\scalefactor},
transform shape
]
\node[inner sep=0pt,use as bounding box,scale={1/\scalefactor},transform shape] at (0,0) (symbol) {A};
\begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
\draw[gray] (-0.5,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,1.6);
\draw[->,line width=\scalefactor*0.3pt, blue] (-0.1,0.1) --++ (70:0.5) node[near start,No, left]{1};
\path[draw,->,line width=\scalefactor*0.3pt,blue]
node[No,anchor=south] at (0.1,1.1) {2} 
(0.1,1.1) to[bend left] (0.9,1.1) 
;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With measuring out the symbol size, like

```
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\symbolwidth{0.5*width("\Symbol")}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\symbolheight{0.5*height("\Symbol")}
```

[image]

```
%\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\begin{document}
\def\Font{\sffamily\Huge} 
%\def\Font{}
\def\Symbol{\Font A}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\symbolwidth{0.5*width("\Symbol")}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\symbolheight{0.5*height("\Symbol")}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\symbolwidth, y=\symbolheight, 
No/.style={-stealth, font=\sffamily\tiny, blue, inner sep=1pt, near start},
]
\node[]{\Symbol};
% Help:
\draw[red] (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
\draw[red] (220:1.5) -- (0,0);
%\draw[] (0,0) -- (1,0);

% Arrows:
\draw[No] (220:1.5) -- +(0.3,1.2) node[No, left]{1};
\draw[No,
postaction={decorate,    decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.1 with {\node[above]{2};}}}
] (120:1.3)  to[bend left] (50:1.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer, however, I think you will have some problems with the arrow size / line width when changing the font size. What is your end goal here ?

Comment: I want consistent arrows (annotations) if I change the fontsize, e.g. `\tiny` instead of   `\Huge`.

Comment: Ok, but more generally, what do you mean to show ? The shape differences with the font sizes ... I am still unsure what you want to achieve

Comment: @BambOo   I would like to achieve: If I change the font size of the symbol, the picture should remain the same, except for the scale.

Comment: I added some code to show you that for different font sizes, even the geometry of the characters may change. Otherwise, when you say "the picture should remain the same except for the scale", do you mean that annotations should look smaller too ?

Comment: Yes, that's the game here:  The annotations should become smaller / larger too.

Comment: I believe I found a suitable solution, see my last edit

Comment: Ahaaa... Looks interesting. Gimme a bit of time to understand.